# How to highlight my currently focused monitor (in multi-monitor display)

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, highlighting, window-focus

I have added a second monitor and am now working in a multi-monitor display (in Windows 7).
I have a constant problem with window focus, where I'm looking at one monitor, doing something with the keyboard, and failing to notice that the actual focus is on another monitor.

The example scenario is like this: I am editing a file in monitor 1. Then something happens in monitor 2 and I respond to it and move the focus there. Then I start thinking about my editing in monitor 1 again, and decide to close the window, and I press "Ctrl+W" to close the editing window - but instead the window at monitor 2 closes!

In short, I am moving my conscious focus between monitors, without moving the "windows" focus between front-windows in each monitor.

I am looking for a solution that will highlight (e.g. red frame) the monitor containing the currently active focused window. Have searched for it but to no avail, and all help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I use dual monitors, but my main focus is always on my 1st monitor, I use the second one only to place applications I am not using now, or applications that I only have open for reference e.g. PDF viewer with an open PDF document for reference.

Whenever I need to focus on an application on monitor 2 I move it to monitor 1 with the Win + Shift + Cursor key shortcut, when I am done I move it back again with the Win + Shift + Cursor key short cut.

It works much better for me at least, plus I don't need to turn my head the whole time between monitors.